# Passing data from Node js to HTML using EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Here's my Server Side code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var title = "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW";
    res.render('Main.html',{name:title});
})
```

Here's my Client Side code(Main.html):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="sm-col-12">
    <h3 contenteditable="true" style="font-family:BentonSans Medium; text-align:center; color:rgb(0,38,99);"><%= name %></h3>                    
    <hr style="border-top: dotted 2px;color:grey" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The output I am getting on Main.html Page is "<%-name%>". Instead, it should print "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW". What exactly wrong in this code?

> Edit:

I forgot to mention that I have also tried other variants like `<%= name%> and {{ name }}`. But I am getting the output `"<%= name%>" and "{{ name }}"` respectively.

Comment: Should that not be `<%= name %>` ? At a glance it looks like a typo where `-` is there instead of `=`. `-` means unescaped ( I think ), but I doubt you meant that

Comment: I have tried that also, but still getting the <%= name%> as output. Not the "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW"

Comment: Did you get it working?  If my answer didn't help can you update your code to show **all** the code on your `app.js` page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

changing it to `<%= name %>` should fix it.

If that doesn't you can try changing `app.set('view engine', 'html')` to `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`, then deleting the following 2 lines.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var title = "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW" ;
    res.render('Main',{name:title}) ;
});
```

I have always written it this way, so I can't say for sure if you syntax is correct, or if ejs will even work without setting it like this.

### Update

Make sure the `Main.html` file is in a folder called `views`, and rename this file to `Main.ejs`.

next change `res.render('Main.html',{name:title});` to     `res.render('main',{name:title});`

Comment: Hey @Jane ! I've also tried the above change that you have mentioned. But still I am getting the same output.

Comment: I figured out the problem (I think).  See my update for the answer.

Comment: Can also use `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'path', 'to', 'views'));` if you want custom views folder

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone I'm pretty sure ejs sets the `views` folder as the default place to look for templates because I've never used that.

Comment: @Jane, updated info worked ! But now I am facing another problem. I have another .html page. And on click of a button, it toggles between these two html pages using window.location.href. But now since I changed Main.html to Main.ejs, it is downloading .ejs file instead of displaying it. How to handle .ejs file through javascript ?

Comment: @Harshkumar can you update your question with code relating to that?  I'm not sure what you need exactly.  If you are just trying to use `<a href="/somePage">`, then you will need to set up a route for `/somePage` on your app.js

Answer (score 2):

```
<%- Outputs the unescaped value into the template
<%= Outputs the value into the template (HTML escaped)
```

As you are looking to print the value instead use `<%=` tag so change  `<%- name%>` to `<%= name%>`

The information can be found here-https://ejs.co/#docs

Comment: I have tried that also, but still getting the <%= name%> as output. Not the "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW".

Answer (score 0):

Change <%- name%> to <%= name%> in your Main.html

Comment: I have tried that also, but still getting the <%= name%> as output. Not the "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW".

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = 5000;

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(express.static('views'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var title = "PERFORMANCE OVERVIEW";
  res.render('Main.html', { name: title });
});

app.listen(port, console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`))
```

Try this and it is rendering HTML page and also accessing the variable you pass in it.

Comment: Hey @shareyar ! I've also tried the above changes that you have mentioned. But still I am getting the same output.

Comment: Check my updated code version hope it will work for you.

Comment: Please could you let me what new you have added in this code ? I too have added the require statements and "listen" route handler in my code as well. My code is working if I convert Main.html to Main.ejs. But is there any way without changing it to .ejs file ?

Comment: Here you dont need to change your file to EJS format you can access data in your html file